# (Java) How to use extended precision arithmetic to handle bigger factorials?

Tags: java, overflow, precision, factorial, arithmetic-expressions

The Program reads in a command-line argument N, and prints `N! = 1 * 2 * ... * N` to standard output.

```
public class Factorial {

    // return n!
    // precondition: n >= 0 and n <= 20
    public static long factorial(long n) {
        if (n <  0) throw new RuntimeException("Underflow error in factorial");
        else if (n > 20) throw new RuntimeException("Overflow error in factorial");
        else if (n == 0) return 1;
        else return n * factorial(n-1);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long N = Long.parseLong(args[0]);
        System.out.println(factorial(N));
    }

}
```

Sample Input(N) and Output(Factorial(N)):

`5 >>> 120

12 >>> 479001600

20 >>> 2432902008176640000

21 >>> java.lang.RuntimeException: Overflow error in factorial`

Remarks:
- Would overflow a long if N > 20
- Need to use extended precision arithmetic to handle bigger factorials

So, my question is how to use extended precision arithmetic to handle bigger factorials in this code?? Is there any other variable type in Java which can hold bigger value than variable long?

Comment: You can use a `BigInteger`. It's a bigger integer.

Comment: Yeah **BigInteger** to hold integer data and **BigDecimal** class to hold decimal data.

Comment: So what is the extended precision arithmetic? It is the " BigInteger"??

Answer (score 1):

`BigInteger` and `BigDecimal` can be used to accurately store very large integer and decimal numbers respectively. You will commonly see them used in recursion.

You can use a combination of `BigDecimal` or `BigIntger` and a `Map` to store and efficiently calculate extremely large things like Fibonacci sequences without slowing your computer down to a crawl.

Maybe you should read up on [BigInteger and BigDecimal](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/math/BigDecimal_BigInteger.shtml). It's usually a good bet to try doing a bit of research first before coming here.